# PostgreSQL limit by group, only show first 2 store options

Tags: postgresql

I need to select first 2 lines where the store_name is different than one given for a given product

```
 id | store_name | prod_name
----+------------+------
  1 |          1 | A
  2 |          1 | B
  3 |          1 | C
  4 |          1 | A
  5 |          2 | E
  6 |          2 | A
  7 |          3 | G
  8 |          2 | A
  9 |          1 | A
 10 |          3 | A
(10 rows)
```

result should be store_name <> 3 AND prod_name ='A'

```
 id | store_name | prod_name
----+------------+------
  1 |          1 | A
  4 |          1 | A
  6 |          2 | A
  8 |          2 | A
```

Comment: Please provide your query, desired and actual result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `row_number()` window function to accomplish this.

**Query #1**

```
    with first_two as (
      select *, 
             row_number() over (partition by store_name
                                    order by id) as rn
        from store_product
       where store_name <> 3
         and prod_name = 'A'
    )
    select id, store_name, prod_name
      from first_two
     where rn <= 2;

| id  | store_name | prod_name |
| --- | ---------- | --------- |
| 1   | 1          | A         |
| 4   | 1          | A         |
| 6   | 2          | A         |
| 8   | 2          | A         |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vmgLsAQ773JN2EtNk57fQD/0)